# Cant get response from API using cURL in php

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm trying to get response from API - I have to send an xml document, and then I should get another xml as an response, but all I got is 'xml error no element found'....

Here is my cURL code in php:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email=' . $email . '&password=' . $password . '&content=' . $xml);
$ex = curl_exec($ch);
```

Unfortunatelly, when I'm trying to echo $ex - the above error is shown.
All of my variables are correct, so does my xml (document is given in $xml variable).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting **Content-Type** header to **text/xml**, but actually you are trying to send the data as **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. Either correct the header, or only send the **$xml** variable.

For example:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Content-Type: text/xml',
   'Content-Length: '. strlen($xml))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is purely so that the response from the remote server gets placed in `$result` rather than echoed.

Comment: I've tried to delete header and echo it - still does not work